# When did megahertz turbo displays first appear?

Tags: clone, turbo, megahertz

Although I love the AT cases that have a numerical clock speed display, I think it must have originally been some gimmick by a lower-level clone manufacturer. I can't think of an IBM or Compaq model that did this. When did these first appear, and additionally, who was the first to do this?

Comment: From vague memory, this feature first appeared in the 286 era, so mid to late 1980s. I do not recall any pre-286 system with this kind of clock speed display, and even custom mods that allowed turbo settings on 8086 systems did not feature this (to the best of my recollection).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This is just a recollection but...*

I remember them arriving sometime between (about) 1986 and (definitely) 1989.

I remember the 2x7-seg LED clock frequency displays appearing soon after 80286 motherboards with a 'Turbo Mode' and its case switch first appeared. These were PC-AT compatibles using a higher-spec 286 with a higher max. clock than the PC-AT's 8 MHz.

The Turbo Mode switch for those early machines switched their 286 clock between two speeds:

- A low speed (normal): roughly equivalent to an 8 MHz IBM PC-AT for compatibility
- A high speed (Turbo): as fast as that 286, its motherboard and RAM could go

You'd put it to normal speed when running software that was tuned to an 8 MHz PC-AT and where the user interface would whizz off too fast to be usable at Turbo speeds.

The 2x7-seg displayed the clock frequency in each mode. The displayed value wasn't an actual measurement, just one of two numbers meant to impress the user. A single LED could have done the same job of indicating Turbo/normal. I think a single LED was used on the first Turbo Mode machines before someone dreamt up the 2x7-seg idea.

I bought a PC clone in early 1990 with a 12 MHz 286 that used no CPU wait states when accessing memory, unlike the PC-AT. In Turbo Mode, the 2x7-seg showed '16' instead of '12' because the resultant speed was effectively double that of an 8 MHz PC-AT. That's sales and marketing for you. In normal mode, mine underclocked the 286 below 8 MHz to get an equivalence to a PC-AT at 8 MHz.

Comment: Some of the displays were configurable with (iirc) DIP switches. You could configure each segment for each of the two speeds. They were most commonly set to show the speeds (or you could lie -- 99MHz, anyone?), or just to say "HI" and "LO".

Comment: The "Turbo" mode was actually the "normal" mode - It typically ran the CPU at its intended speed. The "non-turbo" mode had to apply some tricks (like switching off caches and/or adding memory wait states - the actual CPU clock was the last thing you actually wanted to change on the fly because that required more hardware and synchronisation). The displays were "plain dumb" and didn't "know" anything about the actuall speed of the hardware - As you correctly write, they were hard-coded with jumpers on what to display at which state of the turbo switch.

Comment: Hi @tofro, actually, what you've described's very different to what Turbo mode was and what we had. As said above, the speeds were from the pov of a PC-AT so Turbo meant much faster than PC-AT software would expect, normal was AT speed. This was years after the AT so unsurprisingly there was faster technology (286s, RAM, motherboard ICs) available. I knew the technology then anyway but I also remember the user manuals of mine stating how it worked, back when you got user manuals with a PC.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: My case used an arrangement of jumpers with 14 "T" shapes (one per segment) such that each jumper could be wired to the normally-open contact on the switch, the normally-close contact on the switch, or always be on.  Omitting a jumper would mean the segment would never be on.

Comment: I had one with jumpers like that but it didn't use the switch  I could change modes from the keyboard and get FM sound effects as the PIT clock changed.